# Handlebars issue: TypeError: inverse is not a function on compilation

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am currently stuck on an error and I cannot figure out what the problem is. I am trying to compile on the fly a template extracted from a div present on the page, assign a content to it and display it in a specific div on my page.

My current code looks like the following:

```
var element = $('#project-list-template');
template = Handlebars.compile(element.html());
console.log('template', template);
$('#detail').html(template({object: projects}));
```

The execution of the fourth line raises the following error:

```
TypeError: inverse is not a function
```

The console.log of the template gives:

```
template function ret()
```

Which seems ok to me, of course it is returning a function. For information the element.html() value is as follows:

```
<div class="resources-list project-detail-active">
        <h2 class="text-uppercase">Liste des projets</h2>
        <div id="projects">
            {{#each object "ul"}}
            <li>
              <a onclick="displayProject('#detail', &quot;{{'@id'}}&quot;,  '#project-detail-template')">
                <h2>
                  {{project_title}}
                </h2>
                <p>
                  {{project_description}}
                </p>
              </a>
            </li>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
      </div>
```

If you do have a clue for me, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did find my issue. I simply did add a useless argument to the each helper

```
{{#each object "ul"}}
```

Cannot work when

```
{{#each object}}
```

Does. I was originally using a personal helper where I did actually use this second arguments, so it is a copy/paste error which costs me 2 hours...